# BufferedReader reading online text file without caching text in file?

Tags: android, caching, asynchronous, android-emulator, buffer

I know this sounds weird but i'll **explain**

I've successfully made a **BufferedReader** that will read text from an online text file once the application is opened but the problem is that the first time i open my app **(In Emulator)** it Logs the text `Hello Good World`.After closing the app(Not Pausing) and changing the text in the server to let's say `Hello Good World 2`.I open the app **(In Emulator)** and it Logs `Hello Good World`.I try Restarting my app a couple of times but it still logs the same thing.

**Proof that the online text is being cached**

When i opened the URL from Google Chrome i saw the text `Hello Good World` i refreshed the page and it showed `Hello Good World 2`.Now when i launched my app (From Emulator )it displayed `Hello Good World 2`.

My code:

```
public class checkRemoteFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>{



@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.i("Async","Started");

    String a = "http://www.standarized.com/ads/Test.txt" ;

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    try{
        URL url = new URL(a);

        InputStreamReader isr  = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            result.append(inputLine);

        }
        txtFile = result.toString();
        Log.i("Buffer", txtFile);
        in.close();
        isr.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
       // result = new StringBuffer("TIMEOUT");
        Log.i("Buffer", ex.toString());

    }
    Log.i("GetStringBuffer(result)", result.toString());


    return null;
}   


           }
```

Comment: Maybe there is a caching proxy involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) you can use `useCaches`.
Take a look at that link. 
sample:

```
  URL url = new URL("http://www.standarized.com/ads/Test.txt");
       URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
       urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
         try {
           // Read all the text returned by the server
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            urlConnection.getInputStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline
        // character(s)
        inputLine = inputLine + str;
    }

        finally {
         in.close();
       }
```